# Remove default JRE lib in favour of maven one

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, bouncycastle

I have a maven project and I need to replace the default JRE lib jre/lib/ext/bc-prov* included in the project with those included by my maven pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>     
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>        
</dependency>
```

How can I do?

I'm trying to remove the only bc-prov*.jar from my default JRE libraries, but I can't. The only thing I can do is to remove all the default JRE block.

Thank you in advance!

Marco